# Getting order data between certain period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get orders data between today date until the next date at 4:00 am.

Example

```
Start date : 14/4/2017 12:00 AM
End date : 15/4/2017 4:00 AM

Start date : 16/4/2017 12:00 AM
End date : 17/4/2017 4:00 AM
```

etc ...

How can i achieve this?

Query

```
select * From Orders where BETWEEN and
```

Comment: Show sample data and desired results.

Comment: which sqlserver version?

Comment: version is 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL-Server 2008 and above:

```
declare @start_date datetime = cast(getdate() as date);
declare @end_date datetime = dateadd(hour, 4, dateadd(day, 1, @start_date)) 

select *
from   orders
where dt between @start_date and @end_date
```

Basically add one day and 4 hours to start_date.

> ```
> declare @start_date datetime = cast(getdate() as date);
> declare @end_date datetime = dateadd(hour, 4, dateadd(day, 1, @start_date))
>
> select @start_date, @end_date;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> (No column name)    | (No column name)   
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 15/04/2017 00:00:00 | 16/04/2017 04:00:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=65299f01f1b51ecdd0629d744d4dce1d)*

Answer (score 0):

To get Orders between two dates and specific time:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE date BETWEEN '14-04-17 00:00:00.00' AND '15-04-17 03:59:59.99'
```